# Getting SRVE0190E: File not found error while trying to invoke REST webservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, websphere, cxf

I have developed a simple REST GET service using Spring and CXF.I deployed this in WAS 8.5.5 .When i try to invoke this web service I am getting 404 error.
Below is the WAS server logs.
Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue

I also added `com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRSEngine` property as true in WAS JVM custom properties

```
1/28/15 15:58:04:270 CST]     FFDC Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -IOE ProbeId:1044
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /services/REST/test/status
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor._processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:909)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:890)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:451)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)


Reporter:null
```

Comment: Facing same problem, did you find solution?